# Proof verification of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $1<p<+\infty$.

Define the function $F$
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$
Using Hölder's inequality we want to prove that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x)}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}=0$$
My problem here is that when using Hölder inequality, I find this result
$$F(x)\leq \left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int_0^xdt\right)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$$
which leads directly to
$$\frac{F(x)}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}\leq\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
My problem is with the right hand side. It must tend to zero as $x$ goes to 0. Is this possible despite having the powers outside the integral ? Like, is the condition $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ sufficient to get the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically right. Although I'd like to write
$$0\leq\color{red}{\Big|}\frac{F(x)}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}\color{red}{\Big|}\leq\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}},$$
which will imply
$$\lim_{x\to0}\color{red}{\Big|}\frac{F(x)}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}\color{red}{\Big|}=0,$$
and thus
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}=0.$$
Note that $\phi(x)\leq \psi(x)$ and $\psi(x)\to0$ don't imply that $\phi(x)\to0$.

Your question was: Why $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$? Indeed, if we write $F(t)=|f(t)|^p$, then $f\in L^p$ implies that $F\in L^1$. Since $|F(t)\chi_{(0,x)}(t)|\leq |F(t)|\in L^1$ and $F(t)\chi_{(0,x)}(t)\to 0$ a.e. as $x\to0^+$, by DCT, we have
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^x F(t)\,dt=\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_\mathbb RF(t)\chi_{(0,x)}(t)\,dt=0.$$
For $x<0$, replacing $(0,x)$ by $(x,0)$ will give $\lim_{x\to 0^-}=0$.Finally, since $u\mapsto u^{1/p}$ is continuous, we have $\lim_{u\to0}u^{1/p}=0$, so
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=0.$$

Comment: Offtopic: Funny quote on your profile! :D

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai Ah, I learned it from my topology teacher, see the first page of his notes: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/21F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec01.pdf , where there is a more interesting picture. BTW, is the answer OK?

Comment: Interesting set of notes. I can't verify the answer as it's beyond my knowledge at the moment haha  but thanks for asking me

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Hamdiken You’re welcome.